# Convert Amount from English to other language in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to Convert Amount from English to Bangla in SQL Server? What I want is 12,500.78 to ১২,৫০০.৭৮

Comment: Is there any bulit in functions ?

Comment: Functions to do what? Numeric types have no language. Are you asking how to *format* numeric values into language-specific strings? Why don't you do that in you client application?

Comment: If you want to format a numeric value on the server side use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) with the appropriate culture. On the client side, either set the application's culture to whatever you need, or set the language of individual reports, textboxes, etc. You can also pass the culture to all string formatting functions in .NET

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have done this by creating a custom function that converts English Numeric value to Bangla... here is the function bellow..

```
Create FUNCTION fnGetBanglaAmount
(
    @TransactionAmount NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @length         INT,
            @loopCounter    INT,            
            @subvalue       NVARCHAR(1),
            @banglaValue    NVARCHAR(1),
            @result         NVARCHAR(50),
            @amount         NVARCHAR(50)

    SET @amount = @TransactionAmount
    SELECT @length = LEN(@amount)
    SET @result = ''

    IF(@length > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @loopCounter = 1;
        WHILE(@loopCounter <= @length)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @subvalue = SUBSTRING(@amount, @loopCounter, 1)

            IF(@subvalue = N'.')
            BEGIN
                SET @banglaValue = @subvalue
            END
            ELSE IF(@subvalue = N',')
            BEGIN
                SET @banglaValue = @subvalue
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @banglaValue = CASE
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '0' THEN N'০'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '1' THEN N'১'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '2' THEN N'২'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '3' THEN N'৩'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '4' THEN N'৪'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '5' THEN N'৫'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '6' THEN N'৬'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '7' THEN N'৭'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '8' THEN N'৮'
                                        WHEN @subvalue = '9' THEN N'৯'
                                    END                                 

            END         
            SET @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1     
            SET @result = @result + @banglaValue
        END
    END
    RETURN @result  
END
GO
```

> select dbo.fnGetBanglaAmount(12,500.78)

```
Output: ১২,৫০০.৭৮
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to store the number as a string and have a simple lookup table mapping digits and signs between the two languages, something like

```
ENG    BANG
'0'    '০'
'1'    '১'
...
'.'    '.'
','    ','
'-'    '-'
```

The same (or similar) array can be used to convert in the other direction.

Last, you can define two functions, one that converts a number from Eng to Bang and the other that does the same in the other direction.

Comment: nice and simple, deserve +1 :)

Comment: Very bad actually. Numeric values have **no language**. They are *NOT* stored using individual digits and definitely, no separators are stored. Just their binary values. They don't need any conversion. If one wants them to display them in a specific culture, just use `STRING_FORMAT` with the proper culture, or `String.Format` on the client side

Comment: Well @PanagiotisKanavos, I never tried to convert numbers to other cultures (as you call), not suggested to store numbers in a language dependent way (which, among others, will not support any calculation using them). My suggestion was solely for **PRESENTATION** of the numbers. and besides, if there is a way to do it with some FORMAT function, the function will do exactly what I suggested (about that, I'm 100% sure!).

Comment: Your first line mentions the opposite `One solution could be to store the number as a string`. Culture is the actual name used to describe such things, as  you'll check eg in [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)'s documentation. It's *NOT* a simple substitution either. Sometimes two or three characters are combined as one. Sometimes they appear one of top of the other. The Unicode standard is complicated because languages are a lot more complicated than simple substitutions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant to store it into a variable. Sorry for the bad wording. As for culture, thanks for the description. In this particular case, the suggested method would work smoothly (same number constructs, different symbols). In other cases (like ROMAN numbers) my suggestion will obviously not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRANSLATE function introduced from version 2017:

```
select translate(N'56,789.25', N'0123456789', N'૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯');
```